# Cloudwatch Log Insights syntax for parsing everything before first forward slash

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a JSON Cloudwatch log as below:

```
{"path": "folder1/folder2/file.txt"}
```

My aim is to parse this log so that I can create a new field `parent` from the `path` field such that its value is `folder1`. I basically need to get everything from the beginning till the first forward slash in the `path` field value.

This is what I am trying:

```
fields  @timestamp, @message
| parse @message '"path": "*"' as @path
| parse @path /(^[^\/]+)/ as @parent
```

But it is giving me a syntax error on `as` on line 3 with the error: `'as' is not valid in this position, expecting EOF, '|', '|>'`

I tested the regex expression that I am using at https://rubular.com/r/CXQS8auGY08K0M.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When using the parse command with a regular expression, use named capturing group syntax instead of field aliasing:

```
parse @path /(?<parent>^\w+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

As the message starts and ends with `{}`, you need to add them to the parsing regex. The following should help

```
fields  @timestamp, @message
| parse @message '{"path": "*"}' as @path
| parse @path '*/*' as @parent, @subfolder
```